# Prevent object from going out frame

Tags: java, object, jframe

hello I have created an object that moves left and right but I have an issue trying to make it not go out of the frame for the right side

My frame has a dimension of 200,200

My box has a width of 10 and height of 100, positionned at (50,50)
In order for my box to not go out of the frame when moving to the right

My condition needs to check if 
the current x position + width of the box is inferior or equal to frame width

But the problem is that half of my box still go out frame ( see picture below )

Half of the box going out of the frame

[image]

How I want it to stop

[image]

Thank you for your help

```
public class KeyboardListener implements KeyListener {

    private Component c;
    private Figure f;
    private UserInterface ui;

    public KeyboardListener(Component c, Figure f, UserInterface ui) {
        this.c = c;
        this.f = f;
        this.ui = ui;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && (f.getX() > 0)) {
            f.move(-1, 0);

        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && f.getX() + 10 <= ui.getFrame().getWidth()) {

            f.move(1, 0);
            System.out.println("X pos : " + f.getX());
            System.out.println("Frame width :" + ui.getFrame().getWidth());

        } 

        c.repaint();
    }
}


    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            UserInterface ui = new UserInterface(new Box(50, 50, 10, 100));
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(ui);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How much does `f.move(1, 0)` move the figure ?

Comment: By 1, every time I press the right key it goes from position x : 0 to 1 to 2 to 3 
This is my move method public void move(int dx, int dy) {
  x += dx;
  y += dy;
 }

Comment: Note that you should check if the figure WILL still be within the bounds after the next move (if not, don't move) , that is `f.getX() + 10 + 1 <= ui.getFrame().getWidth()` with your example of moving by `1`. Also you may have the problem of borders counting for the size, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097301/jframe-get-size-without-borders